# Rails: db:migrate inconsistently alters schema.rb on my box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, schema, database-migration

Pulled down some updates from Github and ran the migrations `rails db:migrate` and noticed Git tracking changes to the repo. A shortened diff of `schema.rb` shows it inserting `id: :serial,` everywhere?

Anyone know what's going on? Safe to dump this? It's not present on other developer's machines? Is this a setting I'm not aware of?

```
-  create_table "boxes", force: :cascade do |t|
+  create_table "boxes", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
     t.text "name", default: "", null: false
     t.datetime "created_at", null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
@@ -107,7 +107,7 @@ ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_05_27_143936) do
     t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_boxes_on_user_id"
   end

-  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
+  create_table "comments", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
     t.text "body", null: false
     t.integer "commentable_id", null: false
     t.string "commentable_type", null: false
@@ -116,7 +116,7 @@ ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_05_27_143936) do
     t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes in the generated `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` are often caused when you update your postgres server or you update rails.

To this specific problem, it seems there's already an answer: [What determines if rails includes id: :serial in a table definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598531/what-determines-if-rails-includes-id-serial-in-a-table-definition)

Comment: the answer which you gave as a link just give why it is happening but how to resolve it?

Comment: Usually you don't have to solve anything. Just use the newly generated schema or structure.

Comment: but the newly generated schema forced to fail the test cases and shout "ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint"

Comment: the project started in rails v5.0 and the current version is 5.2, so every new migration alters the old table and changes the type and constraints of the "id" column in the schema.rb

Comment: Maybe ask a question on stack overflow with the stacktrace and the expected behaviour :)